# Tizen WebAPI telephony

Tags: javascript, tizen, telephony

I am trying to find a way to access the telephone within Tizen and its API. There is a `<feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/network.telephony"/>`, but I could not find any example how to call it and gain access to start a telephone call from my JavaScript code.

I am using a Samsung Gear S for development, but the wearable API does not seem to say anything about that.

Answer (score 3):

Solved - turned out to be simple afer some research (unfortunately not well documented by Samsung):

```
var telnumber;

function errCb(error)
{
    alert("errCb: Fehler aufgetreten " + error.message);
}

function successCb()
{
    // alert("Success telephone call");
}

function makeTelephoneCall(telno)
{
    telnumber = telno;
    if (bDebug)
        alert("Notfallnummer rufen: " + telno);
    try
    {
        var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl(
                "http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/call", "tel:"
                        + telnumber);
        tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, null, successCb, errCb,
                null);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert("tizen.ApplicationControl not defined - " + e.message);
    }

}
```

Requires to set the privilige:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/call"/>
```